# Delete a number in a string with regex

Tags: regex

I have this string:

151228-▶ Guido's Lounge Cafe Broadcast 0124 It Will Be Alright (20140718) by Guido's Lounge Café

I want to delete the numbers - "0124" and "20140718" inside the string, but leave the number "151228" at the beginning untouched by regex. I tried so many times, but still couldn't find a way to do that using only one expression. The best I could do was this:

151228-▶ Guido's Lounge Cafe Broadcast It Will Be Alright ) by Guido's Lounge Café

by the expression: [^\d+]\d+

That is almost a success, but the open parenthesis of "20140718" is also deleted.

I am not very good at regex, and that string is just a test for myself. I want to know whether there is a single expression that can deal with it, or if I have to do multiple. Can anybody recommend some articles for me about regex as well? I read some, but many are not very detailed.

i use php, and do some replacing work by preg_replace(regex, "", "$str").  that string showing here is randomly chosen.  so there won't be some special constraints.  actually, i just want to delete the numbers inside the string to test my regex comprehension.  then i failed...

Comment: post your attempts and also the tool/lang you're running..

Comment: tell me the tool that you are using to solve this

Comment: Are there special data constraints that can be taken advantage of?  That is, is "0124" always 4 digits and the 3rd number always enclosed in parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you always want the first number (left of the "-▶") to remain, and all other numbers to be removed. Assuming the language Python you should be able to use a negative look-ahead as follows:

```
print re.sub(r'\d+(?!.*-▶)', '', "151228-▶ Guido's Lounge Cafe Broadcast 0124 It Will Be Alright (20140718) by Guido's Lounge Café")

# output
# 151228-▶ Guido's Lounge Cafe Broadcast  It Will Be Alright () by Guido's Lounge Café
```

How it works: It replaces any group of numbers with an empty string except for the first group. The first group is defined as being to the left of the `-▶` character sequence.

**EDIT (in PHP):**

```
$output = preg_replace("/\d+(?!.*-)/", "", "151228- Guido's Lounge Cafe Broadcast 0124 It Will Be Alright (20140718) by Guido's Lounge Caf");
```

which returns:

```
151228- Guido's Lounge Cafe Broadcast  It Will Be Alright () by Guido's Lounge Caf
```

Answer (score 1):

If it always has the word Broadcast and Alright you can just specify it:

```
toDelete = re.findall('Broadcast ([0-9]+)', line)
toDelete2 = re.findall('Alright ([(0-9)]+)', line)
```

that should pull those numbers out, with the specific data you could then make a function to delete whatever is in toDelete from the line. (by 'line' I mean the line where the string you want to delete things from is) 
I'd write it but don't know what language you're using.

Comment: Do we know what language he is using?  (you might be right)

Comment: Yes, we don't know about the language/tool he is using.

Comment: i use php and do some replacing work by using preg_replace(regexpression, "", $str)

Answer (score 0):

This is really better done with multiple regexes but here's a single one:

```
s/(\d+)([^0-9]+)\s+\d+([^(]+)[(]\d+[)]\s+(.+)$/$1$2$3$4/;
```

And the output is:

```
151228-▶ Guido's Lounge Cafe Broadcast It Will Be Alright by Guido's Lounge Café
```